# Meteor : import svg

Tags: reactjs, meteor, svg

Hello I use meteor to transfer a react app. I need in a JSX file (/imports/test.jsx), to import a file cast.svg. But I have an error : "Error: Cannot find module '/cast.svg'". I put cast.svg in the public folder.
If someone have an idea ? thanks

Comment: Could you please share some code snippets of your current implementation? Specifically, how are you referencing /cast.svg ?